# How to change the direction of arrow of final particles in TikZ-Feynman

Tags: luatex, tikz-arrows, tikz-feynman

I would like the direction of the arrow in the Feynman diagram to be from C to D in the final state. Any guidance or advice on how to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [charged scalar, momentum'=\(\vec{p}_1\)] a -- [charged scalar, momentum'=\(\vec{p}_3\)] i2,
  a [below right, label=\( \)] -- [charged scalar, momentum'=\(q\)] b,
  f1 [particle=\(D\)] -- [charged scalar, momentum'=\(\vec{p}_2\)] b -- [charged scalar, momentum'=\(\vec{p}_4\)] f2 [particle=\(C\)],
};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please. Make. Your. Code. Compile. For us. Thank you

Comment: @ms-spo Thank you. I have now inserted it.

Comment: If you have two questions, post two questions, to avoid being closed. Our approach is to provide many solutions (=answers) to one specific problem (=question). Multi-questions don‘t fit.